# CSS alignment right in desktop view and mobile view alignment center

Tags: html, css

I have an issue when it comes to viewing my website responsive one of the images is a little bit off screen but in desktop view, it supposes to be to the right however in mobile view it should it in the centre like others.

The image is located under:`<!--container for article -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="article-container clearfix">`

[image]

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: #EBEBEB;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li a.active {
 background-color: #F16529;
 color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}
.container {
 margin-left: 25%;
 padding: 1px 16px;
 height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1px 16px;
 }
 div.item {
  width: initial;
  max-width: 256px;

 }
}
div.item {
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 256px;
}
.blog {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.caption {
 display: block;
}
img {
 display: block;
}
img.wrap {
 max-width: 70%;
 margin: 30px 0px;
}
img.align-right {
 float: right;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
div.article-container {
 padding: 5px;
}
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
footer {
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: #EBEBEB;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="sv">
<head>
 <title>Inlämningsuppgift 6</title>
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <!--nav bar-->
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <br>
   <li><img alt="htmll logo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"></li>
   <li>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="active" href="#lank">Länk 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank2">Länk 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank3">Länk 3</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#lank4">Länk 4</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <!--navbar end-->
 <!--container for blog posts 3 images-->
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Innehåll</h1>
  <div class="item">
   <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--end-->
 <hr>
<!--container for article -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="article-container clearfix">
   <img alt="html logo" class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
   <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--end-->

 <footer>
  Skriven i HTML 5.
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    img.align-right {
         float: none;    
        margin: auto;
            max-width: 256px;
    }

    div.article-container {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
       max-width: 256px;
    }
}
```

```css
    body {
     margin: 0;
    }
    ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 25%;
     background-color: #EBEBEB;
     position: fixed;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
    }
    li a {
     display: block;
     color: #000;
     padding: 8px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a.active {
     background-color: #F16529;
     color: white;
    }
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
     background-color: #555;
     color: white;
    }
    .container {
     margin-left: 25%;
     padding: 1px 16px;
     height: auto;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     ul {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
     }
     .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 1px 16px;
     }
     div.item {
      width: initial;
      max-width: 256px;

     }
    }
    div.item {
     vertical-align: top;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 256px;
    }
    .blog {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    }
    .caption {
     display: block;
    }
    img {
     display: block;
    }
    img.wrap {
     max-width: 70%;
     margin: 30px 0px;
    }
    img.align-right {
     float: right;
     margin-left: 30px;
    }
    div.article-container {
     padding: 5px;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
    }
    footer {
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     padding: 1rem;
     background-color: #EBEBEB;
     text-align: center;
    }

 @media(max-width:767px){
  img.align-right {
       float: none;    
      margin: auto;
  }

  div.article-container {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
            max-width: 256px;
  }
 }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <html lang="sv">
    <head>
     <title>Inlämningsuppgift 6</title>
     <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
     <!--nav bar-->
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <br>
       <li><img alt="htmll logo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"></li>
       <li>
        <h2>Menu</h2>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a class="active" href="#lank">Länk 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#lank2">Länk 2</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#lank3">Länk 3</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#lank4">Länk 4</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
     <!--navbar end-->
     <!--container for blog posts 3 images-->
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Innehåll</h1>
      <div class="item">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <img alt="htmll logo" class="blog" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"> <span class="caption">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <!--end-->
     <hr>
    <!--container for article -->
     <div class="container">
      <div class="article-container clearfix">
       <img alt="html logo" class="wrap align-right" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
       <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
       <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <!--end-->

     <footer>
      Skriven i HTML 5.
     </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

add media query for image

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.